# How to zoom in to a specific point smoothly with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to zoom in onto the pencil when hovered over the image.

HTML:

```
<div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 267px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/n9q7jhm.jpg');
    background-size: 400px 267px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

div:hover{
    background-size: 500px 333px;
    background-position: -60px -60px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AX59Y/

[image: Pencil image]

My naive attempt was to increase the size and change the position of the image, however as you can see from the jsfiddle, the transition is very jagged as it tries to accomplish both transitions at the same time.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Try this http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/imagehovers/index.html or make the speed a bit faster http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/AX59Y/2/

Comment: @AamirAfridi thanks, but I already visited that page, and they don't go into zooming to a specific point. And even the first example, it zooms into a corner, not the origin.

Comment: I simply changed the easing method to 'ease-in-out' in stead of just 'ease' and found the performance to be much better, have you tried difference easing methods? Perhaps a custom cubic-bezier could further enhance the performance: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the answer from SW4 and change the left and top changes for a transform origin

```
#image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/n9q7jhm.jpg');
    background-size: 400px 267px;
    background-position:center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 75% 75%;
    transform-origin: 75% 75%;
}
#wrapper:hover #image {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

The 75% 75%  is more or less the position of the pencil , but you can set it to whatever you want.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AX59Y/5/)

Comment: Thanks, this solution is completely smooth.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the transition to scale up and reposition the image on hover, in order to do this you'll need to wrap the image div within a parent with overflow hidden.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/AX59Y/1/)

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='image'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 267px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/n9q7jhm.jpg');
    background-size: 400px 267px;
    background-position:center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#wrapper:hover #image {
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    left:-150px;
    top:-100px;
}
```

Comment: To me, it still looks like the transition is trying to accomplish two different things, alternating between each resulting in a jagged transition. Albeit, a lot smoother than my implementation, I was hoping for a more smoother transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your transition to `linear` it looks much less 'jagged'.

```
transition: all 1s linear;
```

Not sure if this is the behaviour that you want.